# Summarise/reduce N features to one feature

Tags: python, r, machine-learning, time-series, feature-extraction

I have multi-dimensional(`f1,f2,f3`) time-series data as

```
# R CODE
library(xts)
timeseq <- seq(as.POSIXct("2017-06-01"),as.POSIXct("2017-06-20 23:59:59"),"hours")
df <- data.frame(f1=rnorm(length(timeseq),30,1),
                 f2=rnorm(length(timeseq),40,0.5),
                 f3=rnorm(length(timeseq),50, 2))
df_xts <-xts(df,timeseq)
```

Now, I want to reduce this three-dimensional data(`df_xts`) to one-dimensional time-series data.

I tried Multidimensional scaling (MDS) as
 `cmdscale(coredata(dist(df_xts)),k=1)`, but it seems that it looses some information during feature reduction process. Is there any other approach to reduce the features without losing much information?

Comment: Even with one of the most standard feature reduction methods like principal component analysis you lose information dependent upon overlap between various features. For instance, if you perform PCA on your dataset  with `summary(prcomp(coredata(df_xts), scale = TRUE))` , the first principal component only captures 37% of the variance, first two principal components cumulatively capture 70% of the variance, implying that there is very marginal overlap between your series and any approximation will inevitably lead to information loss.

Comment: Contrast this with a dataset such as `data(EuStockMarkets)` which contains stock market index levels for Germany, Swiss, France and UK. With `summary(prcomp(diff(log(EuStockMarkets)),scale=TRUE,center=TRUE))`, the first principal component alone captures nearly 75% of the variance. In this case, one could reasonably proxy the stock market returns data with the first principal component alone.

Comment: @hNu, Thanks for detailed comments. You are right that this approach is dependent upon the nature of data. I am looking still looking for some alternative approach to re-represent three-dimensional data with one dimension.